# How can you add specific text from a string onto a new line when writing to a text file in java?

Tags: java

What should I use to write new line in text file? I have tried using `"\n"` to do this every time I loop through entities but that doesn't seem to work.

```
String entityList="";
for(Entity e:entities){
    entityList+=e.toString()+" "+"X: "+e.getX()+" "+"Y: "+e.getY()+"\n ";
}
PrintWriter saveFile = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("game.txt"));
saveFile.write(entityList);
saveFile.close();
```

Comment: *"Doesn't seem to work":* What happens?

Comment: try `System.lineSeparator()`

Comment: It will add the information to the text file but every entity is displayed on one line. I want it to display each entity on a different line.

Comment: I removed entityList.split(entityList);. I added System.lineSeparator() and it has solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` instead of `\n`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use Notepad for verification, which does not display `\n` as a new line.

You better should make use of `System.getProperty("line.separator")` or `System.lineSeparator()`, which result in a correct display of a new line

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.lineSeparator()` for diplay of text in a new line.